# Regex to match at least 9 alphabets and 1 digit

Tags: regex

I try to find a regular expression which matches strings that contain at least 9 alphabets and 1 digit. The position of alphabets and digit can be anywhere.

**Example strings**

```
rahulkumar1
rahul9kumar
1RahulKumar
```

---

**My current pattern**

```
/[A-Za-z]{9,}[0-9]{0,1}/
```

But it does not work:

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to try in this site https://pythex.org/

Comment: In "...matches strings that contain at least 9 alphabets and 1 digit." please edit to change "1 digit" to "exactly 1 digit" or "at least 1 digit".

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to allow chars a-z A-Z and a single digit:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{10})[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{10})` Assert at least 10 characters
- `[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*` Match at least a single digit between chars a-zA-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/72Jebl/1)

Comment: it should accept only 1 digit

Comment: @vinay Like this `^(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{10})[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$` https://regex101.com/r/72Jebl/1

Comment: @vinay What is the tool or language that you are using?

Comment: @user16320675 You can shorten it like that, but if you make the lookahead specific the pattern can fail sooner in case the string contains a char other than `a-zA-Z\d` in the first 10 chars.

Comment: on the other side, checking `.{10}` is trivial, only test for length, no need to test if each characters is in the set - as I wrote not sure which is better regarding performance (does probably not even matter in this question)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work (JS):

```
let a = "abcedf123.f4ada";
let b = [...a.matchAll(/[a-zA-Z\d]{9,}/g)];
console.log(b);
```

Comment: but there should be atmost 1 digit  it should match with below cases                                                                               rahulkumar1 , rahul9kumar , 1RahulKumar . it should not match with rahulkumar or rahulkumar123

Comment: Ah, ok got that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a function that utilizes regex in order to confirm that the proper requirements are met.

The javascript function below receives a string as a parameter, and will return "true" or "false" depending upon whether it meets the conditions. In this case, the conditions are: 9+ alphabetical characters, exactly 1 integer, and 0 special characters (besides underscore). The regex matches with opposites so that it may delete them and count the remainder. There are multiple ways of doing this. Three regex patterns are used:

- `\D` matches all non-digits.
- `[^a-zA-Z]` matches all non-alphabetical characters, uppercase or lowercase.
- `\W` matches all characters that are not a digit, alphabetical character, or underscore.

I recommend [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com) to learn more, and play with your own regex.

```js
function isValidString (str) {
    let intTotal = str.replace(/\D/g,"").length,
        letterTotal = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").length,
      nonwordCharTotal = str.replace(/\w/g, "").length;
  if (intTotal == 1 && letterTotal >= 9 && nonwordCharTotal == 0) return true;
  return false;
}

alert(
  `
    rahulkumar1 = ${isValidString("rahulkumar1")}
    rahul9kumar = ${isValidString("rahul9kumar")}
    1RahulKumar = ${isValidString("1RahulKumar")}
    rahulkumar = ${isValidString("rahulkumar")}: <1 digits
    rahul1 = ${isValidString("rahul1")}: <9 alphabetical characters
    rahulkumar123 = ${isValidString("rahulkumar123")}: >1 digits
    rahul9kumar! = ${isValidString("rahul9kumar!")}: >0 non-alphanumeric characters
  `
);
```